# What is the meaning of Dhammavicaya

Tags: abhidhamma

What is the exact meaning of the second factor of Enlightenment 'Dhammavicaya'? Does it mean: enquiry of the Dhamma (buddhasasana)? Or is it the enquiry (= tilakkhana) of all dhammas i.c. all phenomena? Or both?

Comment: For a full description, please see Ven. Piyadassi "Seven Factors of Enlightnment" at: https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/piyadassi/wheel001.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sutta says:

> Abiding thus mindful, he investigates and examines that state (dhammaṃ) with wisdom and embarks upon a full inquiry into it. On whatever occasion,
>   abiding thus mindful, a bhikkhu investigates and examines that state (dhammaṃ) with wisdom and embarks upon a full inquiry into it—on that occasion
>   the investigation-of-states enlightenment factor is aroused in him,
>   and he develops it, and by development it comes to fulfilment in him.

The word 'dhammaṃ' above is 'singular' (rather than plural). Therefore, dhammavicayasambojjhaṅgo (the investigation-of-states enlightenment factor) appears to mean examining satisambojjhaṅgo (the mindfulness enlightenment factor) with wisdom.

Answer (score -1):

In the essay [The Seven Factors of Enlightenment](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/piyadassi/wheel001.html), Piyadassi Thera wrote in the footnotes:

> Keen investigation of the dhamma (dhammavicaya)
>
> *Dhamma* is a multisignificant term. Here it means mind and matter (*nama-rupa*); *dhammavicaya* is the investigation or analysis of this
>   conflux of mind and body, and all component and conditioned things.

In Bhikkhu Nanamoli's work on the [Visuddhimagga (Path of Purification)](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nanamoli/PathofPurification2011.pdf), he referred to *dhammavicaya* as investigation-of-states.

In the book [The Seven Factors of Enlightenment](http://www.vipassana.com/resources/box/dhammajiva-sevenfactors-vf10p.pdf), Ven. Dhammajiva wrote:

> When you are mindful, you are able to investigate the primary object.
>   Investigation (*dhammavicaya*) is what differentiates *samatha* from
>   *vipassanā*.   *Dhamma* is mind and matter and *vicaya* is investigation. *Dhammavicaya* is investigation into the operation of
>   mind and matter
>
> In the *samatha* practice, you dwell on the concentration that is
>   being developed, but there is no exploration or penetration into the
>   phenomena.    So the mind  superficially observes the objects without
>   much investigation or understanding of their true nature.
>
> To work with investigation of the *dhamma*, you must penetrate into
>   the phenomena. A yogi must directly note all mind objects and matter
>   (*nāma* and *rūpa*) that arise at each of the six sense doors during
>   the practice. Become familiar with them, investigate them and
>   penetrate into their true characteristics. This is the *vipassanā*
>   practice.